# How to format a song's duration time into minutes and seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am working on a Windows Form Application in which I have a Music Player using the "axWindowsMediaPlayer" component. It can import mp3 and wav files, display the songs in a listbox, save and load a playlist, etc.

Now I want a label to show the elapsed time of the song that is currently playing in the minutes:seconds format.

How would I do that?

Here's one of my tries:

```
int count = (int)axWindowsMediaPlayer.currentMedia.duration;
count--;
elapsedLbl.Text = count.ToString();
```

Here's where I'm stuck.

**[EDIT]** In this moment I have formatted it correctly, but now the count isn't going down.

Comment: Well what representation *have* you got for the elapsed time so far?

Comment: You should review the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure.  If you need more details than that, you'll have to provide us more details with what you have tried.

Comment: I am new here(I registered today) so, how can I insert a code snippet?

Comment: Edit your question. Use the code button in the editor. Snippets in comments should limited to 1-liners where you can highlight code `like this` by surrounding it with a pair of backticks `

Comment: Your question is unclear as to if you are having trouble formatting the elapsed time into minutes:seconds or having trouble getting the elapsed time at all from the axWindowsMediaPlayer component.

Comment: So the information about axWindowsMediaPlayer and the music/song is completely irrelevant then. This should be titled 'how to change a seconds integer into a formatted string mm:ss'. Create the timespan as mentioned in my answer and then format it as mentioned in YoupTubes answer.

Comment: `elapsedLbl.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", count/60, count%60)` It gives you "120:00" instead of "2:00:00". Is this correct result?

Comment: `elapsedLbl.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", count/60, count%60);` Functions, otherwise, the count isn't going down. @MarkShevchenko

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss Try using the "currentPosition" property instead of counting down yourself. Trying to keep track of it yourself is going to be a pain if the user has the ability to change the time around themselves.

Comment: I think `currentMedia.duration` means duration of whole song. You need property that means `currentPosition` or `elapsedPosition`.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to `currentPosition` and it makes it perfect, unless when the time is from 0 to 9 seconds it just shows 0:1, 0:2, 0:3 and so on, until it gets to 0:10. How can I fix that?

Comment: Try using (count%60).ToString("00") and (count/60).ToString("00")

Comment: Or you can modify the string.Format string to be "{0:00}:{1:00}". Which is a little cleaner IMO.

Comment: If your problem is solved, click the checkmark next to the answer that solved it. If none of the answers solved your question, add your own answer below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer. Do not change the title to “[SOLVED]”, that does not mark your question solved in the UI.

Comment: The answer that solved my problem is in this comments box. It isn't in the answers section. @DourHighArch

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Windows Media Player ActiveX control there is a duration and a currentPosition property.

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration

AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition
```

Both are in seconds so then you just have to convert them to the desired format. You can use:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double value)
```

To create a timespan and then with that timespan convert it to a formatted string as YoupTube mentioned. Or manually convert the seconds into minutes and seconds as Mark Shevchenko mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
timespanVariable.ToString("mm:\\ss")
```

Or when you have a DateTime:

```
datetimeVariable.ToString("mm:ss")
```

As Matt Johnson mentioned, here's [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to it.

Comment: Check out this link for more custom datetime formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For timespan, you have to escape the colon.  `"mm\\:ss"` or `@"mm\:ss"`.

Comment: It should also be noted that this will cutoff hours, days, etc. completely. I.e. if the timespan is 3 hours and 20 minutes, this will show "20:00" (only the minutes and seconds portion).

Answer (score 0):

The AxWindowsMediaPlayer object can retrieve the current media item through a `currentMedia` property.  There is a property on this object of `durationString` that returns 'HH:MM:SS' format.  Other formats are possible by using the `duration` object.

AxWindowsMediaPlayer docs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562405(v=vs.85).aspx

IWMPMedia interface docs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx